# php code showing on site despite being in <?php ?> tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a database connection that will show all records in a table. The problem is that the PHP tags are showing when opened on localhost. 
The records are not showing in the table so it might be that I have the incorrect password. Specifically its showing this in localhost on the page:

```
prepare($sql); $cmd -> execute(); $phpProducts = $cmd->fetchall(); foreach ($phpProduct as $phpProducts) { echo ' '; }
Products    Price   Description Availability
' . $phpProduct['Products'] . ' ' . $phpProduct['Price'] . '    ' . $phpProduct['Description'] . '  ' . $phpProduct['Availability'] . '     Edit'; $conn = null; require_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

This is the code for the HTML webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="import" href="/shared/breadcrumb.html">

</head>
<body>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/shared/Style.css">



    <h2>Products Catalog</h2>





    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <ul class="breadcrumb">

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="/products/products.html">products</a></li>

        <li><a href="/api/API.html">API</a></li>

    </ul>





        <?php
        require_once('header.php');
        require_once('db.php');
    ?>

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM phpProducts";

        $cmd = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $cmd -> execute();
        $phpProducts = $cmd->fetchall();

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <th>Products</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Availability</th></thead>
            <tbody>

                foreach ($phpProducts as $phpProduct) {
                echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $phpProduct['Products'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $phpProduct['Price'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $phpProduct['Description'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $phpProduct['Availability'] . '</td>



                    <td><a href="edit.php?admin_id=' . $Admins['admin_id'] . '"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="edit.php">Edit</a></td>



                </tr>';
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>';

        $conn = null;

        require_once('footer.php');
        ?>











</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the file extension? is it `.php`?

Comment: Is PHP installed on localhost? Are you using WAMP or something similar?

Comment: Possibly a type-o but i do not see the opening <?php tag, just the closing ?> If that is a type-o and the PHP code is being dumped to the screen, that means that something in the web server is configured incorrectly and/or PHP is flat out not installed.

Comment: if the extension is `.html` then php code will not execute. so file extension need to be `.php` and also php with apache need to be installed and properly configured onto your system.

Comment: Things to check: 1) is the file extension `.php`? PHP code only runs in actual `.php` files. -- 2) Check for typos of course, is there a `<?php` opening and `?>` closing tag? -- 3) are you accessing the file THROUGH localhost (ie, actually typing `localhost/path/to/file` into your browser), or accessing the file directly? -- 4) is PHP installed and configured on your localhost?

Comment: Im using visual studio and the page is in php. Im using its local host to show the website wihtout it being online. I try could use an include and put the php in a different file.

Comment: what Resantic posted below http://stackoverflow.com/a/41400525/1415724 is correct, unless what you posted isn't your full/actual code. If so, then the answer in its own right, should be marked as the correct answer to this. You've also been told here in comments on [point #2 of this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400268/php-code-showing-on-site-despite-being-in-php-tags#comment70002721_41400268) and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400268/php-code-showing-on-site-despite-being-in-php-tags#comment70002666_41400268) being first.

Comment: `$phpProducts = $cmd->fetchall();

        <table class="table table-striped">` that should have throw you a parse error here as well as `/tr>';
                }
            </tbody>`, once you did get PHP going and running it correctly in your localhost.

Comment: You have way too many errors in your code and how you're running this is unclear. The answers to this are inside both links used to close the question as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have html code inside PHP tags (at the table). Try to echo the HTML or close the php tags before the html and open them up again after the html.

Comment: You are (partially) correct about this. However the OP says that "code" is showing starting from `prepare($sql);` so this suggests that PHP may not be running or they're running this as `file:///` or the PHP interpreter isn't doing its job.